# OSGeo4W Shell 'Command not found'

Tags: osgeo4w, command-line, shell

I have a sh script that I want to use to process raster files.  eg

```
#!/bin/sh
# my first script, 
# copyright, year, Author

r.mask -r

for file in A*chlor_a_4km ; do
  echo "map: $file"
    gdal_translate -a_srs "+init=epsg:4326" -a_nodata 65535 \
      -a_ullr -180 90 180 -90 -co "COMPRESS=PACKBITS" \
      $file ${file}_prep.tif
    r.in.gdal in=${file}_prep.tif out=$file --overwrite

done
```

I'm running from the OSGeo4W Shell, Windows 7, Grass 7.2.2, all freshly installed via OSGeo4W.

The script runs, but it produces eg 'r.in.gdal command not found' but then carries on to the next raster.

I expect this is something to do with the Path?  I've just installed this so can someone please send instructions on how to set the OSGeo4W Shell up for use.

Comment: Your shell script seems to be a unix bash shell script. Under windows and osgeo4w you'll need msys, with grass under OSGEO4W there is also a package called msys-grass. I've never tried this, but i don't think you can execute your script without msys.

Answer (score 3):

The GRASS bin does not get added to your PATH variable by default with the OSGEO4W install (that is, when you open the shell or launch CMD via the BAT shell).  If you want to run 'r.in.gdal.exe' - or any similar function associated with GRASS, you'll have to either manually add the GRASS bin folder to your path or update the o4w_env.bat file in your OSGEO4W\bin folder to include it.

For my install, this is where r.in.gdal.exe was sourced:
C:\OSGeo4W64\apps\grass\grass-7.2.2\bin

You can either add that to your PATH environment variable and will be all set, or add it to the .bat file in the line following "REM start with clean path", and it will work but only out of the OSGEO4W shell.

Note:  you'll also need to add the following dependency with required DLLs to your path, or the exe won't run correctly:
C:\OSGeo4W64\apps\grass\grass-7.2.2\lib

Comment: I added "C:\OSGeo4W64\apps\grass\grass-7.4.0\bin\" to Environment Variables -> Path, but i still can't use gdalwarp/gdal_translate. The exe is in that folder. Is there anything else to do?

Comment: My issue was with gdalwarp, but I didn't realize it was in a different folder: C:\OSGeo4W64\bin\. I added that to path and it worked.